# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.
$$y=9x−(3x)^2, y=0;$$
about the y-axis.

How do I solve this when one of the y value is $0$?

Comment: The two curves intersect at $x=0$ and $x=1$, thus they form a closed region. $y$ is  also the rotation axis. Also, check [Pappus' Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "[washer method](https://magoosh.com/hs/ap-calculus/2017/ap-calculus-review-disk-washer-methods/)":

Trying to solve $y=9x-(3x)^2$ for $x$ we don't get a function, so it needs to be split into the two functions
$$
x=0.5 \pm \sqrt{\frac{2.25-y}{9}}, \ y\geq 0
$$
The volume is then given by
$$
V = \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{9}{4}} \left( 0.5+\sqrt{\frac{2.25-y}{9}} \right)^2 \ dy \ - \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{9}{4}} \left( 0.5-\sqrt{\frac{2.25-y}{9}} \right)^2 \ dy
$$
where $y=\frac{9}{4}$ is the $y$ value where the two functions meet. 
 This works because we are subtracting the volume from rotating the inner function from the volume of rotating the outer function (here are the two functions f(y) in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvfipqsium)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Firstly, notice that $y(x) = 9x - (3x)^{2} = 9x - 9x^{2} = 9x(1 - x)\geq 0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$. Each height $y(x)$ contributes with $2\pi xy(x)\mathrm{d}x$ to the volume of the solid. Hence we conclude the desired volume equals
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}2\pi xy(x)\mathrm{d}x = 18\pi\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}(1-x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Such method is known as the shell integration. Can you proceed from here?